# API failing on brave browser but working in chrome and microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, mapbox, brave

In the beginning luckyOrange is sending some request to the API: **https://settings.luckyorange.net** to fetch some content.

The actual Request URL for this API, which is being shown in other browsers except brave, in the network tab is:

```
https://settings.luckyorange.net/?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2F-84.540584%2C39.136547%2C9%3Fq&s=153484
```

This API is working on the chrome and microsoft edge but not on brave.

In the Brave Browser's console, I am having this response:

```
GET https://d10lpsik1i8c69.cloudfront.net/w.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT           -84.540584,39.136547,9?q:9
```

I have tried:

1. Allowing everything in the 'Site Settings' which is in the URL bar.
2. Debugging my application for any other blockers, none.

Also, When hitting that API directly from another tab, it is giving me the response in all browsers (including brave):

```
{
  "masterID": "181739",
  "only_enhanced": false,
  "offline_form": false,
  "log_console": true,
  "idle_timeout_mins": 10,
  "hubspot": false,
  "ga_events": false,
  "adobe_dtm_events": false,
  "addons": {
    "powered_by": false,
    "white_label": false,
    "beta": false,
    "store_resources": false,
    "gcs": true,
    "rdc": true
  },
  "big_dom": true,
  "keys": false,
  "hash_changes": false,
  "anon_ip": false,
  "polyfill": false,
  "newTracking": false,
  "throttled": 0,
  "offset_bottom": "0",
  "chat_align": "right",
  "text_dir": "ltr",
  "colors": {
    "chat_bg": "#000000",
    "chat_title": "#ffffff",
    "chat_subtitle": "#999999",
    "chat_border": "#ffffff",
    "chat_show_blinker": "1",
    "is_chat_bg_light": false
  },
  "words": {
    "available_for_chat": "",
    "offline_message": "",
    "extra_msg": "",
    "pre_chat_ask_enabled": false,
    "pre1": "Enter Your Name",
    "pre2": "Enter Your Email",
    "pre3": "",
    "pre1_r": false,
    "pre2_r": false,
    "pre3_r": false,
    "pre1_t": "text",
    "pre2_t": "email",
    "pre3_t": "text",
    "btn_yes": "Yes, please.",
    "btn_no": "No thanks.",
    "btn_stop": "Stop asking me.",
    "btn_lbl": "chat",
    "enter_placeholder": "Type here and press &lt;enter&gt; to chat.",
    "you": "you",
    "confirm_close": "Are you sure you want to close this chat session?",
    "paging_operator": "One moment, we're paging an agent...",
    "composing": "is typing...",
    "idle": "is idle.",
    "away": "is away from their keyboard.",
    "closed": "ended the chat."
  },
  "bc_events": false,
  "never_chat": false,
  "scramble": false,
  "dis_mo_chat": false,
  "do_not_record": false,
  "extreme_privacy": false,
  "ga_polls": "0",
  "ga_chat": "0",
  "dom_ready": false,
  "ip": "157.39.8.146",
  "fc": true,
  "site_id": 153484,
  "access_token": null,
  "polls": [],
  "invites": [],
  "tags": ["Quest Panel"],
  "auto": false,
  "now": 1665482096,
  "now_ms": 1665482096676,
  "t": 75.708150863647,
  "ek": "30",
  "enable_chat": false
}
```

Comment: `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` means that Brave shields blocked the content. You need to disable them for that site. EDIT: don't know why you're getting error from `cloudfront.net`, not `luckyorange.net`. Please verify that it's indeed your error

Comment: I'm speculating, but this probably looks like cross-site tracking to brave and gets blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I just made the Shields that are UP to down in brave browser, which is present right to the url with brave symbol.